# Binomial or Poisson ? Which one is correct for the following situation?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A large number of insects are expected to be attracted to a certain variety of rose plant.
A commercial insecticide is advertised as being $ 99 $%$ $ efective. Suppose $2000$ insects infest
a rose garden where the insecticide has been applied, and let $X$= number of surviving
insects.
What probability distribution might provide a reasonable model for this experiment?

#### My guess is it is a case of Binomial since $p=.99$ is very large .

#### But my friends opinions are it is Poisson distribution as  $n=2000$ is very large.

Which one is correct and why ?

Comment: Poisson is a binomial limit case !!!.

Comment: The natural model is binomial. Nowadays computations are easy, so that's what one would use. In the old days one would cross one's fingers and use a normal approximation. The Poisson approximation would be more reliable, but more work.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Do i need to apply Poisson distribution here ? Though $p=0.99$ is large ?

Comment: Work on the number of **surviving** bugs. Then "$p$" is $0.01$. But real world today I would use binomial.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you very much . I have mistakenly considered $p=.99$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural model is binomial. Nowadays, computation is easy, so that is what one would use.

In the old days, one might cross one's fingers and use a normal approximation. One can also note that the probability $p$ that a bug **survives** is given by $p=0.01$. So one could use the Poisson approximation to the binomial, with $\lambda=np=20$. The approximation is undoubtedly adequate, but most things one wants to calculate are still unpleasant to do by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the distribution is binomial.

But, Poisson approximation would also yield very similar results as n is large (Binomial tends to Poisson as n tends to infinity).

Even a Gaussian approximation would not be wrong (Central Limit Theorem).

Answer (score 1):

As an illustration the following has the correct binomial distribution as blue $\circ$s, the very close Poisson approximation as red $+$s and the not quite so close Normal approximation (with continuity correction) as green $\times$s.

[image]

The Normal approximation fails to capture the slight right skewness, while it fails on both sides and the Poisson approximation fails on one side to capture the finite support.